# A person who has developed only in one or many aspects of their life

Tags: word-usage, word-request, adjectives, expressions

What do you call a person who has been developed in only one aspect of their life?
For instance, someone who has just studied and did not achieve any needed experiences in society dealing with different people.
Or a person who has only one skill (i.e. mechanics). It would be so difficult for such a person to get connected to other people.

The terms that can be used in this sense [just some translations from my mother language]:

> - Single/one-dimentional person
> - Single/one-faceted person

What about a person who has developed many aspects of their character. I guess the term:

> "Multi-dimentional" OR "multi-faceted" [translation]

works in this sense.

But I have no idea whether they are natural or not.
I wonder if you could help me with it.

Comment: Are you referring to the opposite of 'jack-of-all-trades'?

Comment: It can be one approach @shin. But not necessarily. I'm about a person who just study or who just works or who only plays sports and has no sufficient experiences in other skills. Such people would possibly face many problems because of lacking enough knowledge about other areas of their lives. They know just one work. I.e. they can only study, work... and they cannot deal with their spouse. Because they don't have any experience or at least they have few knowledge.

Comment: I'm confused... "... and they cannot deal with their spouse." -- On a side note, why would a couple marry each other if they cannot deal with each other in the first place? Do you mean, someone successful in one aspect of life and is a failure in all the other aspects?

Comment: Thank you @shin. That was a logical point. I'll try to clarify that. People try to do their best to achieve their desirable person and get married to. So, such a person, after attracting their partner, will fail in many aspects. Because they don't know how to treat the man/woman in their lives! They don't know what an opposite sex needs because they have never/rarely engaged in such occasions in their lives up to their marriage/friendship. Ghey don't even know how they can make love with their partner because of the lack of experiences...

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be referring to a:

1) [**Specialist**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/specialist) - someone who limits his or her studying or work to **a particular area of knowledge**, and who is an expert in that area

2) **[Monomath](https://www.yourdictionary.com/monomath)** - A person with an extensive knowledge of a **single subject or field**, but little knowledge of others.

Just a note that the 2nd word is not a common word.

Comment: Thank you @shin, but my first part of the question is about a lack or deficiency of someone's character rather than their abilities. By the second question I'm looking for a single word or a compound adjective introducing someone who has many aspects and potential.

Comment: Adding my comment here to the OP, do you mean someone successful in one aspect of life and is a failure in all the other aspects?

Comment: Not necessarily @shin. The person as a studet can be on the track of education yet; someone who just studies, never plays any type of sports, never works, has low amount of or no social activities etc. The same goes for someone who works in this way...

Comment: maybe unilateral and multilateral work in my case! What do you think about it?

Comment: When I hear the word 'unilateral', I think of agreements. Let's wait for other answers.